# How to unit test Spring Integration flow - specifically http outbound gateway

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, spring-integration

I wonder if anyone can help - this has been driving me crazy for days!

I have a fairly simple Spring Integration file that I'd like to unit test. The SI uses an http outbound gateway, and I specifically want to unit test rather than integration test - I do not want to provide a mock http server using something like Spark or MockRestServiceServer.

My SI config looks like this:

```
<int:channel id="modifiedAttractionChannel" datatype="u.o.n.p.i.a.s.AttractionUuid">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="attractionModifiedChannelLogging"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        id="serviceGateway" 
        request-channel="modifiedAttractionChannel"
        url="/attractions/{uuid}" 
        http-method="GET"
        expected-response-type="u.o.n.p.i.a.v.m.Attraction"
        charset="UTF-8"
        reply-timeout="${vader.reply.timeout}"
        request-factory="clientHttpRequestFactory"
        reply-channel="vaderAttractionChannel">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="uuid" expression="headers['#{T(u.o.n.p.i.a.s.AttractionsImportInitializer).HEADER_UUID}'].value" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:channel id="attractionChannel" datatype="u.o.n.p.i.a.v.m.Attraction">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="vaderAttractionChannelLogging"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter 
        id="attractionModifiedChannelLogging"
        expression="'attractionModifiedChannel: header=' + headers['#{T(u.o.n.p.i.a.s.AttractionsImportInitializer).HEADER_UUID}'].value + ', payload=' + payload" 
        level="INFO" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter 
        id="vaderAttractionChannelLogging" 
        expression="'attractionModifiedChannel: header=' + headers['#{T(u.o.n.p.i.a.s.AttractionsImportInitializer).HEADER_UUID}'].value + ', payload=' + payload" 
        level="INFO" />
```

I have written a unit test that wires up a basic spring context and am able to get the `modifiedAttractionChannel` and `send` an appropriately built `Message` with an `AttractionUuid` payload and header value.

My unit test can assert that the log message written to `attractionModifiedChannelLogging` is as I expect it (I created the `AttractionUuid` and `Message`, so I know the payload and header values)

What I now need to do is assert the value written to the `vaderAttractionChannelLogging` wiretap. IE. I need to assert a message with a given header value - no problem, I created the header value as part of the test - but also the payload.

In this case the payload is the output of the outbound gateway. Given that this is a unit test and I don't want any dependency on anything else, I have provided a mock `ClientHttpRequestFactory` which in turn provides a mock `ClientHttpResponse` via a mock `ClientHttpRequest`

This works great in that I can control the response body that the outbound gateway would otherwise receive. However, the `RestTemplate` calls its `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` in order to convert the response body into an object via the `MessageConverter`s

Whilst this works in respect of the execution of the SI flow, it means the instance of `Attraction` that is on the reply-channel `vaderAttractionChannel` is not in control of the test; and therefore I cannot make any assertions about it in respect of what gets logged on the `vaderAttractionChannelLogging` wiretap.

I *think* one way of addressing this is to be able to wire in a mock or stub `MessageConvertor` instead of the standard set that returns a fixed `Attraction` instance. But I can't for the life of me work out how to!

Note: The scenario above is a much simplified version of what I'm actually trying to do. I'm not really trying to write unit tests around logged values! I need to test the overall flow of my SI, and being able to control the instance of the `Attraction` that the outbound gateway returns is very much key to that.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated;
Cheers

Nathan

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is; "...the `RestTemplate` calls its `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`..." - it's the other way around. If you really want to unit test the flow, you should provide a normal result from the mock that will be converted by the standard converters. If you really want to mock the conversion, use the `message-converters` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Gary. In this case I do want to mock the standard converters because the output object of the outbound gateway is used further down the SI flow. Your suggestion of using `message-converters` has worked for me, so thanks for suggesting it. If you want to answer this question with your suggestion I'll gladly mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks again;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what your issue is; "...the RestTemplate calls its HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler..." - it's actually the other way around. If you really want to unit test the flow, you should provide a normal result from the mock that will be converted by the standard converters. If you really want to mock the conversion too, use the message-converters attribute.